# Android BottomSheet?

Tags: android

I would like to use bottom sheets in my application. As you may know, there's no official implementation for this, however there are few projects on GitHub. I found the Flipboard's version, but that doesn't work under API level 14 and my program targets API level 8. I found another one, but unfortunately that doesn't allow me to set a layout/view for the bottom sheet or creating modal bottom sheets neither.

What now?

Comment: how about this one ? https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet

Comment: As I see it only grants me to create bottom sheets with menus and not layouts, so it is not good for me. But thanks anyway.

Comment: you can give try with custom dialog with using animation.

Answer (score 0):

Official support for BottomSheets was added to the Android Design Support Library as of version 23.2.0